# Delay between loops (iterations) like in Grinder

Tags: multithreading, loops, process, jmeter, grinder

In the Grinder, I have given load test parameters as

```
grinder.threads = 30
grinder.process = 3
grinder.runs = 2
grinder.processIncrementInterval = 45000(ms)
```

which means I have 4 process with 30 threads each, each process starting at an interval of 45 seconds & repeating for 2 times.

I want to achieve the same thing in JMeter, but am unable to do it. If I set `loop count = 2, threads = 30, ramp-up = 45 secs`, the no. of threads gets multiplied by that count & threads increases.

I want 30 threads to first start (finish or not finish-does not matter) and after 45 seconds, next 30 threads to start & go on. There is no process concept in JMeter. So am not sure how to go about simulating the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can try to use [Stepping Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup) or even better [Ultimate Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup) from [jmeter-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) set.

Looks like

> 30 threads to first start (finish or not finish-does not matter) and after 45 seconds, next 30 threads to start & go on

scenario can be completely set via Ultimate Thread Group.

Comment: I tried Ultimate Thread Group also, but in that you have to mention the Hold Load Time which is a specific duration, but in my case I want the threads to complete the entire test plan. Immaterial of the first set of threads performing or non-performing on the server, I want my next set of threads to start.

Comment: Since more load is applied, my threads can take more time to complete one iteration than the Hold Time I have given. So this might not solve my problem.